# how to install cmvision package for ros indigo

Tags: ros, cmvision, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am new to ros and may be this is a silly question. But please help.
I am not able to install cmvision package for ros indigo using following command

sudo apt-get ros-indigo-cmvision

The error I get is: 'E: Invalid operation ros-indigo-cmvision'

Please help. Thanks in advance!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/254172/how-to-install-cmvision-package-for-ros-indigo/) by [vacky11](https://answers.ros.org/users/29229/vacky11/) on ROS Answers with karma: 272 on 2017-02-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> The error I get is: 'E: Invalid operation ros-indigo-cmvision'

`apt-get` is telling you that it doesn't understand what you want, as `ros-indigo-cmvision` is not an `apt-get` command.

The correct command would be:

```
sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-cmvision
```

note the `install` there.

But in this case that is not going to work either, as [cmvision](http://wiki.ros.org/cmvision) has not been released for anything but ROS Hydro (note the lack of any mention of any other ROS release on the wiki page). If you still want to use the package, you'll have to build it from sources. See #q252478 for some info on how to do that. [kbogert/cmvision/indigo-devel](https://github.com/kbogert/cmvision/tree/indigo-devel) appears to be a fork of the original `cmvision` package that has been updated to work on ROS Indigo.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-02-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0